# Weather based reminders

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web app that will send me a reminder or alert based on a weather event?

Such as:

- 24-48 hours before freezing, I could set an alert to remind me to shut off the outside hose
- 4 hours before rain, remind me to close all the windows in the house

Ideally I'd want to be able to customize the alert based on the weather/forecast trigger that I choose

Comment: How do you expect to be receiving alerts? Email? SMS? Telepathy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a perfect use case for **[ifthisthenthat](http://ifttt.com)**

> Put the internet to work for you by creating tasks that fit this simple structure:
>   *if this then that*.
>   Think of all the things you could do if you were able to define any task as: when something happens (this) then do something else (that).

Have a look at the list of [weather channel triggers](http://ifttt.com/channels/weather).

[image]

Comment: ifttt to the rescue again!  thanks

Comment: I just found out about this, and was coming to post another answer. Looks like I was beat to it.

Answer (score 3):

[Weather.com](http://www.weather.com) sends me text messages based off of certain conditions. It sends these alerts to SMS on certain carriers and to email. https://registration.weather.com/ursa/alerts/step1